# Why does angular 2 component influences the style of the actual html it hosts?

Tags: css, angular

i've created a component that is based on a material card listed here (migration from Jquery)
https://github.com/marlenesco/material-cards

One thing i've noticed, that the styling of the card is not right- as seen here:
https://ibb.co/cg28hm.

It appears that the app-component html element is the issue here.

When I edited the HTML - I tried 2 things:

1. Removed all "additional" styling received for the component - did not work.
2. removed the actual "html tag" of the component - **then everything worked**.

That means, when i removed the "app-component" manually from:

```
<app-component _ngcontent-c0 _nghost-c1>
   <div>... </div>
<app-component>
```

to

```
   <div>... </div>
```

the card was in its correct style.

Any idea why this even happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue, of course the new component that is added ruins the CSSes (as it is a complex CSS that uses hirarchies, and suddenly an "app-component" tag stops the css hirarchy..), so i've just used directive:

```
selector: '[app-component]',
```

and in the component:

```
<div app-component> </div>
```